# Time spent between log entries in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table which tracks the user actions in a web-site. A simplified version is as follows

```
user_id | action_time             | module_name
--------+-------------------------+------------
1       | 2014-03-02 11:13:08.775 | home
1       | 2014-03-02 11:13:08.345 | user
1       | 2014-03-02 11:13:08.428 | discussions
```

How much time did a user spend on each screen? So take the least `action_time` for a user, get the next one, find the difference.

I think this calls for a recursive query, but not able to get my head around it. One thing - I wouldn't know when to stop. After some "module" the user could have just closed the browser, without bothering to logout. So "closure" is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be surprisingly simple with the [window function `lead()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html)

```
SELECT *
     , lead(action_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY action_time)
      - action_time AS time_spent 
FROM   tbl;
```

That's all.

`time_spent` is `NULL` for the last action of a user, where no other action follows - which seems perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 0):

this example of how to make a 'range aggregate' using windowing functions and a lot of nested subqueries. I just adapted it to partition and group by user_id, and it seems to do what you want:

```
SELECT user_id, min(login_time) as login_time, max(logout_time) as logout_time
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, login_time, logout_time,
        max(new_start) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY login_time, logout_time) AS left_edge
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, login_time, logout_time,
            CASE 
                WHEN login_time <= max(lag_logout_time) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY login_time, logout_time 
                ) THEN NULL 
                ELSE login_time 
            END AS new_start
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                user_id, 
                login_time, 
                logout_time,
                lag(logout_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY login_time, logout_time) AS lag_logout_time
            FROM app_log
        ) AS s1
    ) AS s2
) AS s3
GROUP BY user_id, left_edge
ORDER BY user_id, min(login_time)
Results in:



 user_id |     login_time      |     logout_time
---------+---------------------+---------------------
       1 | 2014-01-01 08:00:00 | 2014-01-01 10:49:00
       1 | 2014-01-01 10:55:00 | 2014-01-01 11:00:00
       2 | 2014-01-01 09:00:00 | 2014-01-01 11:49:00
       2 | 2014-01-01 11:55:00 | 2014-01-01 12:00:00
(4 rows)
```

It works by first detecting the beginning of each new range (partitioned by user_id), then extending and grouping by the detected ranges. I found I had to read that article very carefully to understand it!

The article suggests it can be simplified with Postgresql>=9.0 by removing the innermost subquery and changing the window range, but I could not get that to work.